# PTIJ: Was Avraham a firebender?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

B"H

It says pretty explicitly "He took in his hands, the fire", if he didn't know firebending, then how did he not get burnt?

Let's also not forget how he was thrown into the fiery furnace and survived

BUT the thing is is that Avraham is usually associated with Chesed, which represents water [see end of Tanya ch. 5], so what was he?

I was thinking perhaps the Avatar is mainly one element, but also has the power to use other elements, so perhaps one can say that here as well

So based on that, it would imply that Avraham was originally born in the water tribe, but, as the Avatar, learned firebending later.

The only thing, is that its also implied strongly that Moshe was a waterbender, as it says "I'll call him Moshe, because from the water I've drawn him", as well as his ability to split the sea, and bring forth water from the rock.

However, if we count the cycle of Avatars, given that Moshe is the 7th from Avraham [see Basi Legani 5710 and midrash there in beginning] then it doesn't seem to work, if both Avraham and Moshe were [mainly] waterbending Avatars, let's see.

So if we assume Avraham was originally a waterbender, because he represents Chesed, then it stands to reason that Yitzchak would be fire, because that's Gevurah, and given that the 4 elements go in the order of Hashem's name [see Likutei Torah Shlach] with:

air being Yud, Chochmah;
fire being first Hey, Binah;
water being Vav, Chesed [Z"a, hamshacha]
Earth/Dust being last Hey, Malchus

AND if we're going in the order of first water [Avraham, Chesed] then fire [Yitzchak, Gevurah] then the Avatar order is seemingly:

Avraham -- Water
Yitzchak -- Fire
Yaakov -- Air
Yehudah (king of brothers) [or another brother, not sure about this one] -- Earth
Kehos [again not sure who it would be in this generation, or if it skips etc...] -- Water
Amram [probably] -- Fire
Moshe -- Air

so then Moshe would be air! And even though there are several instances where its's implied that Moshe was a pretty big expert at airbending, such as when he flew to Italy with the angels in the clouds to get esrogim, as well as when he jumped to the top of Mount Nevo in one leap, or when he flew into outer space, above the stars to cause the plague of hail [see Rashi there], but still, based on the fact that his name represents water, it would stand to reason that he was mainly a waterbending Avatar, and just picked up airbending later in life, but the things is, if we assume Moshe is water, then let's work backwards:

Moshe -- Water
Amram -- Earth [if we assume same direction as before]
Kehos -- Air
Yehuda/other brother -- Fire
Yaakov -- Water
Yitzchak -- Earth
Avraham -- Air

then Avraham would be mainly an airbender, but what specific relation does Avraham have to air? Even though it says in the Maamer Gadol Yihyeh 5722 that the first Beis Hamikdash is the first hey, which has a revelation of Chochmah [Air, Yud], which also refers to Avraham who called Mount Moriah a "mountain" [similar to Binah], and the 2nd temple is the latter Hey, representing Malchus [element of Earth], which corresponds to Yitzchak who called it a field [Lasuach Basadeh, in the place of the temple], and assuming the first temple was from above to below, since it represented the service of Tzadikim [as mentioned in the beginning of the maamer there] and the second temple was from below to above, since it represented the idea of Baalei Teshuva, and given that Yitzchak is similar to the element of Earth in the sense that he could only stay in the holy *land*, but still, how would Avraham be related to air?

And where did he learn that firebending mentioned earlier, anyway?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: any reason for the misTearEeIs downvote?

Comment: Sadly downvotes are often anonymous, which is not helpful criticism. Best to accept and keep going.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand how your Avatar Cycle works. The Avatar Spirit is only reborn when the previous Avatar dies. So that means that the next Avatar after Avraham wasn't even someone from the Avot or their children (for Yaakov and Esav weren't yet married at the time) - it was an unknown person who was born when Avraham died. It is possible that Moshe was also an Avatar, but since we don't really know who was in-between or how many Avatars there were, it would be difficult to make any assumptions on problems with the cycle of the elements between Avraham and Moshe.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> In fact, unless we say that Avraham was the first Avatar, it is difficult to see how he was an Avatar at all, considering he lived to see Noach and Noach's children. Unless we were to say that one of the wives was the Avatar and she died when Avraham was born.

Comment: based on the concept of ibur neshamos end of tanya ch. 14 i was thinking one can said to "born" even in their own lifetime

Comment: @YitzchakL Oh, interesting. However, still not in line with traditional Avatarology. :)

Comment: well traditional avatarology, like all ologies, are only *based* on the Torah, but in the real world, the rules are a bit different

Answer (score 0):

The Michtav Me'Eliyahu says that had Avraham actually done the *akeidah*, then there would have been *techiyas ha'meisim* and Yitzchak would have come back to life and *mashiach* would have come.

Now we know that the war of Gog and Magog is a nuclear war, as it says in Zecharia 14.12 (https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%22%D7%92_%D7%96%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94_%D7%99%D7%93_%D7%99%D7%91)

> וְעֵינָיו תִּמַּקְנָה בְחֹרֵיהֶן
>
> And their eyes shall melt in their sockets

Which is what happened in Horishima.

So it is *muchach* that the fire that Avraham sought to control was nuclear fire. Now we know that nuclear energy is posited e=mc2, i.e. energy and matter are different forms of the same thing, i.e. at this *madregah* there is no *chiluk* between *esh* and *mayim*.

So your question is not valid.

Comment: is that first fact about moshiach and the akeida actually true? If so its pretty cool, I never knew that. I wonder why the angel stopped him, then. Also is there a citation?

Comment: @YitzchakL My Michtav Me'Eliyahu is in a shipment, it will be in the *maphteach*.